# Elevating process via ShellExecuteInfo - Infinite shells?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, elevation, elevated-privileges, shellexecuteex

I followed [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320748/Haephrati-Elevating-during-runtime) for elevating a process, however in my code below (pretty much a copy currently), when debugging, I get an infinite number of shells being created. The line it happens on is indicated.

I've looked at the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this hasn't given me much insight.
Please advise what I'm doing wrong?

I'm new to c++.

```
wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath)))
{
    // Launch itself as admin
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { sizeof(sei) };
    sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
    sei.lpFile = szPath;
    sei.hwnd = NULL;
    sei.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
    if (!ShellExecuteEx(&sei)) //get infinite shells here
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError == ERROR_CANCELLED)
        {
            // The user refused to allow privileges elevation.
            std::cout << "User did not allow elevation" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //other lines of code omitted.
    }       
}
```

Comment: It looks like you launch a copy of yourself, which launches a copy of itself, which launches ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roger is right: you are launching a copy of the program that launches a copy of the program etc. etc. - what is missing is the `IsAppRunningAsAdminMode()` function from the article you are linking: you should call it first and then try to launch a new elevated copy of the program only if it returns false - i.e. only if the current execution program is not elevated.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried the below next, but the "fIsRunAsAdmin" is marked as undefined??  

`IsAppRunningAsAdminMode();
 if (fIsRunAsAdmin = false){
  //elevate process
 }
 else {
  //do nothing since process already elevated
 }`

Comment: @NickProwse: did you copy the function itself from the article into your source code?

Comment: @NickProwse: `fIsRunAsAdmin = false` assigns `false` to `fIsRunAsAdmin` - what you want is `fIsRunAdAdmin == false` - or better `!fIsRunAsAdmin`

Comment: Yes I copied the function from the article. Ok I've now change it to `fIsRunAdAdmin == false` I still get `fIsRunAsAdmin` being marked as undefined though?

Comment: Did you define that variable? You should have something like `bool fIsRunAdAdmin = IsAppRunningAsAdminMode();` in your code.